# Cannot load ruby-debug in ruby 1.8.7 on a Mac OS X 10.7.3 Lion

Tags: ruby, ruby-debug

Cannot load ruby-debug on a Mac OS X 10.7.3 Lion.

Not sure why the path is incorrect.

Ruby version is 1.8.7 which came standard with Lion.

Installed Xcode

```
Developer Information:

  Version:  No version information available
  Location: /Applications/Xcode.app
  Applications:
  Xcode:    4.3 (1175)
  Instruments:  4.3 (4321)
  SDKs:
  Mac OS X:
  10.6: (10K549)
  10.7: (11D50a)
  iPhone OS:
  5.0:  (9A334)
  iPhone Simulator:
  5.0:  (9A334)


$ sudo gem install ruby-debug -v 0.10.4
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at          /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/linecache-0.46 for     inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/linecache-0.46/ext/gem_make.out


$
```

Looking for the ruby.h path on the Lion system, the path's are different.

```
./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/Headers/ruby.h
./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin10.0/ruby.h
./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/Headers/ruby.h
./Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin11.0/ruby.h
```

What is the best approach from this point?

thanks,

pb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:  Xcode 4.3 needs to be installed and then from Xcode Preferences-General the Xcode Command Line Tools must be installed.

Without the Command Line Tools the above errors are generated.

Once installed, Ruby-Debug loads.

```
$ sudo gem install ruby-debug -v 0.10.4
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed linecache-0.46
Successfully installed ruby-debug-base-0.10.4
Successfully installed ruby-debug-0.10.4
3 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for linecache-0.46...
Installing ri documentation for ruby-debug-base-0.10.4...
Installing ri documentation for ruby-debug-0.10.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for linecache-0.46...
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby-debug-base-0.10.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby-debug-0.10.4...
$ rdebug -v
ruby-debug 0.10.4
```

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, you will (and in all actuality, should) install Ruby via RVM, located [here](http://beginrescueend.com/). Once you havee done that you will need to install your Rubies like so

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p290 --with-gcc=clang
```

The important part is `--with-gcc-clang`, which tells the system to use clang. From there your gems should install for the version of Ruby you specified in the install command.

Comment: Why is the base ruby and gem which comes with Lion failing to install ruby-debug?  I have ruby 1.8.7 base 249 working fine with ruby-debug (0.10.3) under os x 10.6.8.  I understand what you are suggesting, just confused why I can not rebuild my production environment with debug?

Comment: Do you regularly install gem with sudo?

Comment: In production yes, but in development no, i put the gems in ~home/usr.  What do you recommend?

Comment: This is the command  run from my home directory, where I have a ./usr directory structure.  The same path issue occurs.

Comment: $ gem install ruby-debug -v 0.10.3 -i ./usr
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
Gem files will remain installed in /Users/pblen/usr/gems/linecache-0.46 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/pblen/usr/gems/linecache-0.46/ext/gem_make.out
$

Comment: rvm is installed and i plan on learning it.  i see definite benefits. thanks for pointing me in a new direction.

Comment: rvm, coupled with gemsets (and bundler) makes maintaining differing requirements/rubies/gems quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

*I faced same problem while trying to install rails on my Lion. This is how i could solve it.*

Install rvm

`$ curl https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable`

Install osx-gcc-installer

https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Installed new version of ruby

`rvm install 1.9.3`

Typed to following command to show the requirements

`rvm requirements`

To use an RVM installed Ruby as default, instead of the system ruby:

`rvm system ; rvm gemset export system.gems ; rvm 1.9.3 ; rvm gemset import system.gems # migrate your gems
    rvm alias create default 1.9.3`

Installed rails:

`sudo gem install rails`

My Mac is now read for rails!! YAY!!